# How to test Jasmine Tests in Travis for PHP environment?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, travis-ci

I have a PHP project where I also have Jasmine JavaScript tests. How can I run the Jasmine tests in an PHP environment (since my server-side code runs in PHP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a tool, [OpenPhantomScripts](https://github.com/mark-rushakoff/OpenPhantomScripts), with the goal of making it really easy to just run your Jasmine tests on Travis.  It just shells out to phantomjs, so it should still run in your PHP Travis environment.

Comment: Roland: If this answer helped you, please mark this as an "accepted answer". It marks this question as answered and gives Mark credit for answering a question.